# How to implement per file thumbnail for file association?

Tags: windows, winapi, thumbnails, file-association

I have a file type that I want to associate with my program. I could make every file of that type have the same standard icon like how all HTML files look the same or all txt files, but what I want to do is have every file show a preview of itself for its thumbnail, more like how jpg, bmp, and png show a thumbnail of that particular image file.

I mostly work in C# but I know something like this may require a little (or a lot) of C++ to do what I want to do and I'm ok with that if need be. I don't know where to begin as I've never tried this before. A little googling says that a COM object will do it, but I need more to go on than that.

**EDIT**
Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

namespace APKIconHandler {

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("000214fa-0000-0000-c000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761852(v=vs.85).aspx
    interface IExtractIcon {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the location and index of an icon.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uFlags">One or more of the following values. This parameter can also be NULL.use GIL_ Consts</param>
        /// <param name="szIconFile">A pointer to a buffer that receives the icon location. The icon location is a null-terminated string that identifies the file that contains the icon.</param>
        /// <param name="cchMax">The size of the buffer, in characters, pointed to by pszIconFile.</param>
        /// <param name="piIndex">A pointer to an int that receives the index of the icon in the file pointed to by pszIconFile.</param>
        /// <param name="pwFlags">A pointer to a UINT value that receives zero or a combination of the following value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        ///
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetIconLocation(IExtractIconuFlags uFlags, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 2)] StringBuilder szIconFile, int cchMax, out int piIndex, out IExtractIconpwFlags pwFlags);

        /// <summary>
        /// Extracts an icon image from the specified location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pszFile">A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the icon location.</param>
        /// <param name="nIconIndex">The index of the icon in the file pointed to by pszFile.</param>
        /// <param name="phiconLarge">A pointer to an HICON value that receives the handle to the large icon. This parameter may be NULL.</param>
        /// <param name="phiconSmall">A pointer to an HICON value that receives the handle to the small icon. This parameter may be NULL.</param>
        /// <param name="nIconSize">The desired size of the icon, in pixels. The low word contains the size of the large icon, and the high word contains the size of the small icon. The size specified can be the width or height. The width of an icon always equals its height.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Returns S_OK if the function extracted the icon, or S_FALSE if the calling application should extract the icon.
        /// </returns>
        [PreserveSig]
        int Extract([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile, uint nIconIndex, out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, uint nIconSize);
    }
    [Flags()]
    public enum IExtractIconuFlags:uint
    {
        GIL_ASYNC=0x0020,
        GIL_DEFAULTICON =0x0040,
        GIL_FORSHELL =0x0002,
        GIL_FORSHORTCUT =0x0080,
        GIL_OPENICON = 0x0001,
        GIL_CHECKSHIELD = 0x0200
    }

    [Flags()]
    public enum IExtractIconpwFlags : uint
    {
        GIL_DONTCACHE = 0x0010,
        GIL_NOTFILENAME = 0x0008,
        GIL_PERCLASS = 0x0004,
        GIL_PERINSTANCE = 0x0002,
        GIL_SIMULATEDOC = 0x0001,
        GIL_SHIELD = 0x0200,//Windows Vista only
        GIL_FORCENOSHIELD = 0x0400//Windows Vista only
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum IconHandlerReturnFlags {
        SimulateDoc = 0x1,
        PerInstance = 0x2,
        PerClass = 0x4,
        NotFilename = 0x8,
        DontCache = 0x10
    }

    public class APKHandler : IExtractIcon, IPersistFile {
        private const int S_OK = 0;
        private const int S_FALSE = 1;

        [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
        public void DllRegisterDll() { }

        public void GetClassID(out Guid g) {
            g = new Guid("405a310a-b439-49b9-894a-cc55ffc6e91d");
        }

        public void GetCurFile(out String str) {
            str = "CurFile";
        }

        public int IsDirty() {
            return S_OK;
        }

        public void Load(string pszFileName, int dwMode) {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "Load :" + pszFileName + " , " + dwMode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public void Save(string pszFileName, bool save) {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "Save :" + pszFileName + " , " + save + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public void SaveCompleted(string pszFileName) {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "SaveCompleted :" + pszFileName + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public int GetIconLocation(IExtractIconuFlags uFlags, StringBuilder szIconFile, int cchMax, out int piIndex, out IExtractIconpwFlags pwFlags)//Using IExtractIcon and IPersistFile.Load
        {
            piIndex = 0;
            pwFlags = 0;
            try {
                pwFlags = IExtractIconpwFlags.GIL_PERCLASS | IExtractIconpwFlags.GIL_DONTCACHE | IExtractIconpwFlags.GIL_NOTFILENAME;
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "GetIconLocation...");
                return S_OK;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "GetIconLocation " + e.Message);
                return S_FALSE;
            }
        }


        public int Extract(string pszFile, uint nIconIndex, out IntPtr phiconLarge, out IntPtr phiconSmall, uint nIconSize)//Using IExtractIcon 
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ApkHandler.txt", "Extract...");
            phiconSmall = phiconLarge = IntPtr.Zero;
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
}
```

I have edited my registry as the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instructs (thanks arx).

I've toyed and tweaked with this over and over and have yet to had any of my functions called (as indicated by ApkHandler.txt never appearing). I disabled UAC so I don't think there's any permissions issues with creating the file in the root, I do it all the time while debugging. I'm trying not to get frustrated but this is really getting under my skin.

Comment: [Thumbnail Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Icon Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @arx: In the end, probably both.

Comment: I can't find anything about actually implementing these. I don't know how to have the OS pay attention to my DLL. Are there any tutorials for how to write an Icon Handler from scratch?

Comment: The page I linked to has "Step 3: Registering Icon Handlers".  This shows the registry entries you need to create to associate your icon handler with a file extension.  And steps 1 and 2 explain how to create the icon handler.

Comment: A working example with even the slightest amount of code would do me much more good than paragraphs. I've read over those pages and others many times and yet to have even a hint that my Icon Handler is running.